# Why debugging on real iOS devices does not send network packets

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, networking

I am developing an iOS app which requires sending UDP packets. When I test the app on the **simulator**, I can receive the packets from another computer. However, when I attached **my phone** to the computer and run it, the phone does not send out network requests.

I think the problem is that I need to let the app ask permission from the user, but I do not know how to write it.

I am sending UDP packages with using [SwiftSocket](https://github.com/swiftsocket/SwiftSocket), and here is my code: https://github.com/lxylxy123456/FGFS-Controller

Comment: Network may be different.. Perhaps: `10.100.0.10` refers to a computer on a different network. AFAICT, that is a local IP and the phone may not be aware of it. Maybe the phone and the computer are on two different networks..

Comment: But I am sure that the phone does not send any packets out. I had tried changing `10.100.0.10` to other IP addresses.

Comment: Use CharlesProxy to check if the phone sends out any data: https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/using-charles-from-an-iphone/ . You run it on your computer, then you connect your phone to your computer's IP and all requests your phone sends out will be recorded on your computer. That way, you can check what calls are being sent and what ones aren't.

Comment: It returns the error 'Optional(SwiftSocket.SocketError.unknownError)'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I cannot use an IP Address to request authorization. For my app, I can change the "IP Address" field to "apple.com" or "stackoverflow.com", and grant the APP the permission to access network, and then all data would be transferred successfully (after switching back to my IP Address).